# Can I change the bundle ID of an existing app, already in App Store?

Tags: iphone, app-store, bundle

I'm pushing out an update for an app. I wonder if I can change the bundle ID. If not, what are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't change bundle ID for an update. You need to update the version number in info.plist file.